# Pandas DataFrame from list of lists of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data structure that is a list of lists of dicts:

```
[
    [{'Height': 86, 'Left': 1385, 'Top': 215, 'Width': 86},
     {'Height': 87, 'Left': 865, 'Top': 266, 'Width': 87},
     {'Height': 103, 'Left': 271, 'Top': 506, 'Width': 103}],
    ...
]
```

I can convert it to a data frame:

```py
detections[0:1]
df = pd.DataFrame(detections)
pd.DataFrame(df.apply(pd.Series).stack())
```

Which yields:

[image: stacked data frame]

This is almost what I want, **but**:

How would I turn the dictionary in each of the cells into a row with columns 'Left', 'Top', 'Width' 'Height'?

Comment: For flattening the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To add to [Psidom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42304526/1391671), the list can also be flattened using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

```
from itertools import chain

pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(detections)))
```

In my experiments this was about twice as fast for a large number of "chunks."

```
In [1]: %timeit [r for d in detections for r in d]
10000 loops, best of 3: 69.9 µs per loop

In [2]: %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(detections))
10000 loops, best of 3: 34 µs per loop
```

---

If you *actually* want the index in the final data frame to reflect the original grouping, you can accomplish this with

```
pd.DataFrame(detections).stack().apply(pd.Series)
```

```
       Height  Left  Top  Width
0   0      86  1385  215     86
    1      87   865  266     87
    2     103   271  506    103
1   0      86  1385  215     86
    1      87   865  266     87
    2     103   271  506    103
```

You were close, but you need to apply `pd.Series` *after* stacking the indices.

Comment: Thanks Igor. The last line is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 7):

You can loop through the list, construct a list of data frames and then concatenate them:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in detections])

# Height    Left    Top  Width
#0    86    1385    215     86
#1    87     865    266     87
#2   103     271    506    103
```

---

Alternatively, flatten the list firstly and then call `pd.DataFrame()`:

```
pd.DataFrame([r for d in detections for r in d])
```