# How to recursively scrape table from pages using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am new to python and I'm trying to scrape a table and from a website that has multiple pages. How should I try to make my code use `.click()` and where should the code be placed to get a dynamic scrape of the table.

The website I'm trying is https://free-proxy-list.net/ and I'm able to get the table from the first page. I'm trying to get all the pages and put them into a pandas data frame. I have already put the info from the table into a dictionary and tries to put the dict inside a dataframe. However just the first page is able to be inserted into the dataframe. I need all the data from the other pages as well

Comment: Found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304447/pandas-dataframe-from-list-of-lists-of-dicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Initialized empty list.
2. Use while loop with condition to check max_page count and iterate the loop.
3. Append the list in each page iteration.
4. added the list into pandas Dataframe.
5. Import the entire data into CSV file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://free-proxy-list.net/')

page=1
max_page=15
IP=[]
Port=[]
Code=[]
Country=[]
Anonymity=[]
Google=[]
Https=[]
LastCheck=[]
while page<=max_page:

 rows= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='proxylisttable']/tbody//tr")))
 for row in rows:
    IP.append(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]').text)
    Port.append(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text)
    Code.append(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[3]').text)
    Country.append(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]').get_attribute('textContent'))
    Anonymity.append(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]').text)
    Google.append(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[6]').get_attribute('textContent'))
    Https.append(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[7]').text)
    LastCheck.append(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[8]').get_attribute('textContent'))


 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-controls='proxylisttable' and text()='Next']"))).click()
 page=page+1
 print('navigate to page: ' + str(page))

driver.close()

df=pd.DataFrame({"IP":IP,"Port":Port,"Code":Code,"Country":Country,"Anonymity":Anonymity,"Google":Google,"Https":Https,"Last_Checked":LastCheck})
print(df)
df.to_csv('output_IP.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tried to put all my data into a dictionary and managed to scrape the pages :) Thanks for your answer!